# Dynamically load a tag for a list of objects of different types

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, collections, jsp-tags

I have a list of objects that are very different but need to be part of one list. e.g. A list of widgets on a page (weather, clock, facebook..). It needs to be in one list as this list needs to be ordered into chunks of 10, randomised and paginated.

A high-level view of my current solution looks like this:

One Abstract Base Class:

```
abstract class MyBaseClass
{
 Object getMe()
 {
  return this;
 }
}
```

A Common Parent Class

```
public class Common extends MyBaseClass
{
  public String commonMethod()
  {
    return "somestring";
  }
}
```

Other classes

```
public class A extends Common
{
   public String method_1_ForA();
   public String method_2_ForA();
}

public class B extends Common
{
   public String method_1_ForB();
   public String method_2_ForB();
}
```

An implementation of this would look like:

```
public class MyQuickTest
{

 public void test()
 {
   List<A> listA = new ArrayList<>();
   List<B> listB = new ArrayList<>();

   List<Common> listCommon = new ArrayList<>();
   listCommon.addAll(listA);
   listCommon.addAll(listB);

   foreach(Common common:listCommon)
   {
      common.getMe(); //will return an object of type A or B
   }

 }
```

}

In order to display the above I will have to return the above list with a custom tag lib and iterate over the list of objects in my jsp. Then for each object I would have to check the type and then call the appropriate jsp/.tag to render the item.

My Questions are:

1. Is there a better way to support this than to return 'object' from the base   class?
2. How can I avoid having to write if's in my JSP? is there a way that I can load a tag purely based on type? - google tells me no.. or if not load by type is there any other technologies, approaches  or design patterns out there that would provide the more elegant solution?

i.e.

Current Solution:

```
/// loop
 <c:if test="${type==A}"> call render A JSP </c:if>
 <c:if test="${type==B}"> call render B JSP </c:if>     
// end loop
```

Hopeful Solution:

```
//loop
  <dispatcher type="${type}"/> //load the appropriate render tag for the object
//end loop
```

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have managed to find solutions for the above two questions (Q1, Q2). My findings below:

Q1. I do not need to have a base class that returns object; as long as all the sub classes inherit from 'Common' I can return a list of Common and get the subtype information using instanceof. So taking into consideration the original example, I can omit the abstract class 'MyBaseClass' and instead do the following.

```
public class MyQuickTest
{

 public void test()
 {
  List<A> listA = new ArrayList<>();
  List<B> listB = new ArrayList<>();

  List<Common> listCommon = new ArrayList<>();
  listCommon.addAll(listA);
  listCommon.addAll(listB);

  foreach(Common common:listCommon)
  {
   if(common instanceof B)
   {
    B b = (B) common;
    String s = b.method_1_ForB();
    //do some other logicfind solutions for the above problem.
   }
  }

}
```

Q2. There are two options:
   i. load the html chuck as part of the object (A decorator pattern would be the most applicable). This is very similar to the approach taken by sitemesh. So the pseudocode would be something like:

```
//loop
 <c:out value='${common.renderMe}'/> //print the string output (this can be the output of a velocity, thymleaf template render)
//end loop
```

ii. Load the appropriate JSP dynamically and do a JSP include. A JSP include's unfortunately can't take an object as an argument therefore you need to use an approach as the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435347/enchanced-jspinclude-implementation) where you use nested scoped variables.

*I chose to go with option 'ii' as there is a clear separation of concerns i.e. the object does not need to know how it's rendered instead it's all dedicated the JSP. The JSP approach was also more intuitive to other team members and kept with what was a common approach to our existing project *